# A/B Testing on two separate servers

Tags: testing, nginx, server

This may be a silly question. I have two separate servers - different machines, different IPs, different websites. One is Nginx and another is an unknown kind (client won't tell hehe). Is it possible to have "domain.com" (which is currently pointing to the unknown server) to be an A/B testing domain. Where 50% will visit domain.com and see the unknown server, with its full functionality, and the other 50% will visit the same domain and see my nginx server, with its full functionality.

The reason why they have to be separate is because the client who is asking for this refuses to share access to their current, unknown, setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could serve DNS records [round-robin-style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_DNS), where both IP addresses as are served as valid A records. Although this will have drawbacks; for example, if the cached DNS record expires while a user is browsing the site, they may abruptly switch the other server and thus be logged out or lose similar session data (assuming the servers don't share session data with each other).

Perhaps a better solution would be to pass all traffic through a load balancer. The load balancer could be configured to randomly pick the server to direct traffic to, and remember this choice semi-permanently based on the user's source IP.

Comment: You mean a third server, used mainly as a "routing" server? These two sites are online stores. It would be best to avoid the user being redirected mid-purchase.

Comment: Yes, it's a third server. For example, AWS offers [Elastic Load Balancing](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/details/#details) as a service. See the "Sticky Sessions" feature for an example of this.